# No overload for method 'ProjectTo' takes 0 arguments

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, iqueryable, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

Error

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   CS1501  No overload for method 'ProjectTo' takes 0 arguments
```

C#

```
       public static async Task<PagedResult<U>> GetPagedAsync<T, U>(this IQueryable<T> query, int page, int pageSize) where U : class
    {

        var result = new PagedResult<U>();
        result.CurrentPage = page;
        result.PageSize = pageSize;
        result.RowCount = await query.CountAsync();

        var pageCount = (double)result.RowCount / pageSize;
        result.PageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling(pageCount);

        var skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
        result.Results = await query.Skip(skip)
                                     .Take(pageSize)
                                     .ProjectTo<U>()
                                     .ToListAsync();
        return result;
    }
```

I am getting above error after migration core 6.0 to core 7.0

[image: strong text]

Comment: have you installed AutoMapper package?

Comment: Yes installed latest version  Automapper 12.0.0

Comment: do you have any other assemblies that have an implementation from `ProjectTo`?

Comment: No, we didnot use

Comment: @User have you added `using AutoMapper;` on top of the class?

Comment: using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions; 
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; 
using System; 
using System.Linq; 
using System.Threading.Tasks;  this added in class @viveknuna

Comment: Read the error message! The method `ProjectTo` requires at least 2 Arguments (of type "AutoMapper.IConfigurationProvider" and "object") as described in the intellisense box ;)

Answer (score 2):

[`ProjectTo` methods](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/QueryableExtensions/Extensions.cs) provided by `AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions` require `IConfigurationProvider`. You can use one from `IMapper` or try resolving `IConfigurationProvider` directly:

```cs
IMapper mapper = ...; // resolve from the DI

var result = query
   .ProjectTo<SomeClass>(mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
   // ...
   ;
```

Or

```cs
IConfigurationProvider cfg = ...; // resolve from the DI

var result = query
   .ProjectTo<SomeClass>(cfg)
   // ...
   ;
```